# how to set form at proper location with background image on different sizes of screen

Tags: html, css, forms, image

I have one background image with `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;`

I want to show form on specific part of image. The problem is as device changes location of specific part of form  is also changed.

Ref Image:

[image]

I have already tried few popular screen sizes as shown [here](http://screensiz.es/monitor) with media query.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .bottom-right {
            position: absolute;
            top: 29%;
            left: 57.5%;
            color: white;
        }
}
```

bottom-right is class of my form.

But, as its using media query working only under rule.

I want, it should stay fixed to its spot irrespective of the screen size.

Comment: Where is HTML ? I suggest you to use `position` property rarely

Comment: @NishargShah its just a image and form with "bottom-right" in body as shown in ref image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a coordinate system that doesn't rely on any units - such as pixels or centimeters. To do so, you'd get the pixel co-ords of the top-left and bottom right of your box that indicates the form's desired position and divide them by the image's dimensions. You'll now have fractional coords. 0,0 is the top-left and 1,1 is the bottom-right.

Once you know how large the image is displayed in pixels, you can compute how far to move your form.

The top-left (inside the border) is at 588,84 and the bottom-right is at 838,458.
 Since the image is 940x604, the recomputed coords are:

Top Left: 588/940, 84/604   (0.6255,0.1391)

Bot Right: 838/940, 458/604   (0.8915,0.7583).

Now then. If we'd like to show the image at 50%, we can compute the coords of our rectangle as follows.

(0.6255 * 940 * 0.5), (0.1391 * 604 * 0.5)

(0.8915 * 940 * 0.5), (0.7583 * 604 * 0.5)

otherwise put,

Top-Left: 294,42
Bot-Right: 419,229

In order to prove our work, we could resize the image to 50% in an image editor and check the coords of the corners. I've done so - the coords are correct. ;)